# Problem with "hat" and keybinding in TeXShop

Tags: texshop

In TeXShop i have made key bindings. Here's an example:

> input: ^ , output : ^{#INS##SEL#}

So the idea is when i write `e^e` in the editor it should type `e^{e}`. Instead it types `eê`. Is there a way to disable the formatting feature of the three symbols  ,`´`,`¨` and `^` in TeXShop, or is there a smart way of treating the problem?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Comment: What localization are you using? If ^ is a dead key (i.e., it has to be followed by another key and becomes a single, accented character you can't make a Key Binding for it. Good Luck,
Herb Schulz